# Did I misuse a reference variable in a simple OpenMP for loop, or is it a clang bug?

Tags: c++, openmp, clang++

I think I have found a clang++ bug, but would appreciate advice on whether my code is correct. Clang static analyzer thinks it is okay, and it compiles with no problems, but when compiled with clang 3.7, it gets the size off a passed reference vector completely wrong. GCC and clang 3.8 both give the correct answer. I've reduced it to this test case:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
// including or excluding omp makes no difference
#include <omp.h>

void doSomething(std::vector<int> &k) {
#pragma omp for
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i) {
            std::cout << k.size() << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);

    std::vector<int> &j = v;
    doSomething(j);
    return(0);
}
```

with libomp (I think), rather than libgomp:

```
clang-3.7++ -fopenmp clang-err.cpp
./a.out
18446708892352074976
18446708892352074976


clang-3.8++ -fopenmp clang-err.cpp
./a.out
1
1
```

I could not find such a bug present in clang 3.7 but fixed in 3.8. I do not know how to tell whether I am using libomp for sure, although this is how LLVM/clang was compiled. It seems like such a simple thing, so I suspect I am doing something strange rather than there being a real clang bug.

If the consensus is a clang bug, I'll report it against 3.7. Thanks.

Comment: [seems fine on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29538f674e7e3ca7)

Comment: I suggest modifying the code slightly such as `auto const p = &k` and `p->size()` and see whether anything changes if the OMP loop accesses a pointer rather than reference.

Comment: Does it work with `#pragma omp parallel for`?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. James Root: you're right, adding parallel makes the error go away in clang 3.7. However, in my original code, I have a for block in a parallel block, so this isn't an option as a work around. Do we agree this is a clang 3.7 bug?

Comment: Following Ben Voigt's suggestion, `p->size()` does produce correct output. I think I can use that as my work-around. LMK if you think this is a clang bug.

Comment: If GCC and Clang 3.8 agree, it seems likely that it is a bug in 3.7. After all, that was the first Clang release with OpenMP support, was it not? Bugs in first generation implementation are common...

Comment: For good measure, you could compare to the Intel compiler.

Comment: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25042

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be a [clang bug](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25042) in the current release 3.7. However, surprisingly, the bug assignee closed the bug against 3.7 because it is fixed in 3.8.